# MySQL where SUM(value) is more than a specific value in a UNION query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

the following query doesn't work:

```
(
    SELECT *
    FROM `items`
    WHERE `name` LIKE '%SCAR%' AND `rarity` = 'Legendary'
    ORDER BY weight / RAND( ) DESC
    LIMIT 0, 1
)

UNION

(
    SELECT *
    FROM `items`
    WHERE `rarity` = 'Legendary'
    ORDER BY weight / RAND( ) DESC
    LIMIT 0, 3
)

UNION

(
    SELECT *
    FROM `items`
    WHERE `rarity` = 'Epic'
    ORDER BY weight / RAND( ) DESC
    LIMIT 0, 1
)

GROUP BY
    weight
HAVING
    SUM(value) < 100

ORDER BY
    RAND()
```

This works alone, however:

```
(
    SELECT *
    FROM `items`
    WHERE `name` LIKE '%SCAR%' AND `rarity` = 'Legendary'
    ORDER BY weight / RAND( ) DESC
    LIMIT 0, 1
)

UNION

(
    SELECT *
    FROM `items`
    WHERE `rarity` = 'Legendary'
    ORDER BY weight / RAND( ) DESC
    LIMIT 0, 3
)

UNION

(
    SELECT *
    FROM `items`
    WHERE `rarity` = 'Epic'
    ORDER BY weight / RAND( ) DESC
    LIMIT 0, 1
)

ORDER BY RAND()
```

How would I go about adding condition that all the rows selected from the database have a sum of value field of at least a set value such as 1000? Thanks

Comment: You need to treat your overall UNION as a subquery.

Comment: @Uueerdo would you be able to help me this? As I'm not so good with SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT stuff 
FROM (unions) AS u 
GROUP BY u.somefield 
HAVING SUM(u.anotherfield) < somevalue
;
```

Make the unions a subquery. But note that selecting non-aggregated, non-grouped fields is generally frowned upon, disallowed by all but MySQL (and even it's most recent versions' default configurations do not allow it), and probably a very bad idea for this kind of query.

Also, `RAND()` does not always behave the way you think it should. In your UNIONed queries you will probably be dividing each weight by a different RAND() value (since it has to be evaluated for each weight); but your final `ORDER BY RAND()` could be ordering all results using the same single RAND() value since mysql may take a shortcut and only evaluate it once.

Comment: I'm not too fused about the last ORDER BY RAND() that's just to randomly jumble the records a bit for when I display them on my website from AJAX request but how can I make/ensure the weight be divided by different RAND()?

Comment: It looks like that `ORDER BY RAND()` should be fine, according to the docs [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) at least. _I seem to recall otherwise, but that could have been with a pre-5.x version of MySQL._

Comment: query isn't working quite right, like once I said when value is more than 1000 (SUM(u.anotherfield) > 1000) it queried back nothing. and I tried SUM(u.anotherfield) < 4000 and it brought back 4 records that equal about 2800. How do you make a grouped field? I put in a new field called type and gave them all the same value called item to try use that as item field, but I got nothing still. Is there any other way to calculate SUM of value field? Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm not sure why you expect different behavior, the way you are limiting in the queries you are unioning, you have no guarantee any of the 5 records from the union will have a value > 1000, let alone more than one of the same weight.

Comment: On further thought, I get the impression that you are trying to use a query to generate contents (totaling a specific value) for a random "loot bag"; I really don't think sql is the way to go for something like this.

Comment: Any suggestions? If anything, I don't need the query to bring out a specific value. I just need my weighting odds to be good enough to produce decent results all the time.